# spriteWithSpriteFrameName equivalent in cocos2d 3.0?

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone

I'm trying to make my first iOS game and I need to batch render background tiles. I'm using cocos2d 3 but every single sprite drawing example I can find uses `spriteWithSpriteFrameName` which is no longer an option.

I'm successfully loading the sprite sheet/plist:

```
[[CCSpriteFrameCache sharedSpriteFrameCache] addSpriteFramesWithFile:@"backgrounds.plist"];
CCSpriteBatchNode spriteBatch = [CCSpriteBatchNode batchNodeWithFile:@"backgrounds.png"];
```

But I can't figure out how to properly obtain a specific portion of the spritesheet. `spriteWithSpriteFrameName` is no longer a method for `CCSprite`

```
CCSprite* tile = [CCSprite spriteWithSpriteFrameName:@"dirt.png"];
```

Comment: there's an API reference for that: http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/docs/api/Classes/CCSprite.html#//api/name/spriteWithSpriteFrame:

Comment: But there's no equivalent to `spriteWithSpriteFrameName: NSString`, the only thing that accepts a string is image itself. There's something that accepts `CCSpriteFrame` but there's no clear indication on how to use that.

Comment: then look into the ccspriteframe reference, pretty sure there'll be a "with name" initializer, either that or in spriteframecache (spriteframenamed or something)

Answer (score 2):

In cocos2d v3.0 you have to make a sprite frame, than make the CCSprite using the prepared sprite frame:

```
CCSpriteFrame* sampleFrame = [CCSpriteFrame frameWithImageNamed:@"dirt.png" ];
CCSprite* title = [CCSprite spriteWithSpriteFrame:sampleFrame];
```

Hope it helps :)

Answer (score -1):

This is how to do it:

```
CCSprite* spriteFile = [CCSprite spriteWithImageNamed:@"file.png"];
```